# JPA cant delete @OneToOne if @JoinTable is defined

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, one-to-one, join

I have a funny 'problem' i.e. phenomenon.

**Quick Infos:**

- `_BaseEntity` is a `@MappedSuperclass` that handles ID, hashCode, equals, compareTo etc and works fine throughout all my projects)
- I'm using Payara (EclipseLink) on MySQL DB
- `@Expose` is a *GSON* tag
- I have found lots of similar topics, but none answer my question, or make the distinction with/without `@JoinTable`, or get answered in a solving manner...
- the relation is one-sided, i.e. only from `Thema->TopThema`, and explicitly NO `TopThema->Thema`

**WORKING EXAMPLE**
When I have an entity set up like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Thema.TABLE_NAME)
public class Thema extends _BaseEntity {
    static public final String TABLE_NAME = UEntity.TABLE_PREFIX + "Thema";

    @Expose @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true) 
    private TopThema topThema;
}
```

I can simply *EntityManager.remove()* it.

.

**EXAMPLE NOT WORKING**:

**But** if it's defined like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Thema.TABLE_NAME)
public class Thema extends _BaseEntity {
    static public final String TABLE_NAME = UEntity.TABLE_PREFIX + "Thema";

    @Expose @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true) 
    @JoinTable(name = TABLE_NAME + "_topThema")
    private TopThema topThema;
}
```

(having an intermediate table "GP_Thema_topThema", as defined by `@JoinTable(name = TABLE_NAME + "_topThema")` then *EntityManager.remove()* throws an exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`test_PT_local`.`GP_Thema_topThema`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_GP_Thema_topThema_topThema_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`topThema_ID`)
>   REFERENCES `GP_TopThema` (`ID`))

I know that it does not make much sense, to have an extra `@JoinTable` in use, when the reference could also just be saved inside "GP_Thema" as 'GP_Thema'.'TOPTHEMA_ID'.
Plus: both Entity definitions just work equally well on the Java side.

But out of interest: why is JPA not able to remove the entry in the `@JoinTable` `GP_Thema_topThema`, even though I set `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` and `orphanRemoval = true`?

**Update:** And because of the `@JoinTable` I also cannot 
 - delete TopThema first, then Thema (throws `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` on TopThema delete)
 - det Thema.topThema = null, then update (throws `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`again)

Comment: Did you define the inverse side of the association in `TopThema`? If so, please post that entity as well

Comment: Nope, this is only one-sided. Thanx for the hint tho ;-)

Comment: Does it solve your issue?

Comment: Does WHAT solve the issue?

Comment: Have you tried `@JoinTable(
        name = TABLE_NAME + "_topThema"",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "topThema_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GP_TopThema")
)` ?

Comment: I mean have you tried using join table with mentioning join  column name  as above ?

Answer (score 1):

Is not JPA not being able to delete the entity but the actual database. What you are looking for is a deferrable constraint and that is not possible in MySQL.

Mysql docs regarding defferable constraints [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

> Like MySQL in general, in an SQL statement that inserts, deletes, or updates many rows, InnoDB checks UNIQUE and FOREIGN KEY constraints row-by-row. When performing foreign key checks, InnoDB sets shared row-level locks on child or parent records it has to look at. InnoDB checks foreign key constraints immediately; the check is not deferred to transaction commit. According to the SQL standard, the default behavior should be deferred checking. That is, constraints are only checked after the entire SQL statement has been processed. Until InnoDB implements deferred constraint checking, some things are impossible, such as deleting a record that refers to itself using a foreign key

Have you considered switching to [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-set-constraints.html)?

> DEFERRED constraints are not checked until transaction commit

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanx a lot man! Dont have the time to test the problem on Postgres before bounty time runs out, but this looks like a valid answer. Will check with PG and Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

As side note, you can delete your `Thema` entity using JPA and MySQL ... To do so, you just need to declare the foreign keys of your `@JoinTable` (GP_Thema_topThema) as "ON DELETE CASCADE" ...

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE GP_Thema_topThema(
    thema_ID integer NOT NULL,
    topThema_ID integer NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (thema_ID)
        REFERENCES thema (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (topThema_ID)
        REFERENCES top_thema(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

That way if the database receives the command of deleting a `Thema` entity, then any related `GP_Thema_topThema` entities (or tuples) will be deleted also ...